# Couldn't install http-cookie gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need just to execute one .rb file but it needs a lot of additional libraries. Some of them were installed but I have problems with http-cookie. It says:

```
$>gem install -http-proxy http://myproxy:8888 http-cookie
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing http-cookie:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180126-8844-1titamy.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-static-libstdc++
        --without-static-libstdc++
        --with-stdc++lib
        --without-stdc++lib
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:457:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:542:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:557:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:775:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1002:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:944:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:997:in `have_library' from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/mkmf.log
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ex
t-0.0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0
/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/gem_make.out
```

mkmf.log:

```
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe conftest.c -L. -LC:/Ruby24-x64/lib -L. -pipe -lx64-msvcrt-ruby240 -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7: return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

I used Rubygems v2.7.4.

Please help with any advice!
Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Either your Development tools are missing or are mis-configured.

Answer (score -1):

> - Install the ruby development-kit for windows

Comment: OP is obviously using Windows. `apt-get` is usually not available there. Installing linux headers is unlikely to help on this platform...

Comment: @HolgerJust Had not figured that out thanks for the correction